# Только первое и последнее значение подписи координаты Х matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

Сделал график из данных по цене Биткоина с 03.01.2021 по года по 25.04.2021 с шагом в неделю. Но поскольку значений достаточно много, то подписи на оси абсцисс сливаются и становятся нечитаемые. Можно ли как-то вывести только первое и последнее значение(03.01.2021 и 25.04.2021)?

Вот так это выглядит
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: [Что делать с ответами на вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 2):

[Встроенные в Pandas методы визуализации](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/visualization.html) отлично подстраивают временные надписи под осями в зависимости от длительности временного интервала.

Алгоритм действий:

- создайте DataFrame с данными, которые вы хотите визуализировать
- установите в качестве **индекса** столбец с датой/временем. Тип данного столбца должен быть - `datetime64` (**не строки**).
- теперь можно рисовать графики, воспользовавшись методом `DataFrame.plot()` - по оси `X` будут значения индекса (**Pandas сам позаботится о том, чтобы надписи не сливались**).

PS код в ответе я не приводил, потому что вы не привели свой код в вопросе и не предоставили [воспроизводимый пример данных](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/7060/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B5-%D1%8D%D1%84%D1%84%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81-%D1%81%D0%B2%D1%8F%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D1%81-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%B8-%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%BC-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD).

Answer (score 0):

Да, конечно можно. На странице [документации](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.xticks.html) есть пример как настроить ось `x`.

Пример оттуда:

```py
>>> locs, labels = xticks()  # Get the current locations and labels.
>>> xticks(np.arange(0, 1, step=0.2))  # Set label locations.
>>> xticks(np.arange(3), ['Tom', 'Dick', 'Sue'])  # Set text labels.
>>> xticks([0, 1, 2], ['January', 'February', 'March'],
...        rotation=20)  # Set text labels and properties.
>>> xticks([])  # Disable xticks
```

А, если вам совсем неохота разбирать что, да, как можете заглянуть [сюда](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/text_labels_and_annotations/date.html). Там пример работы с датами на оси.